# Calculate 3 Month Rolling Count of values in a column Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, rolling-computation

I have the following dataframe (this is a simplified version of the dataframe, but the logic is the same):

```
#MONTH = yyyy-mm-dd

    MONTH        User
0   2021-04-01   A
1   2021-04-01   B
2   2021-05-01   B
3   2021-06-01   A
4   2021-06-01   B
5   2021-07-01   A
6   2021-07-01   B
7   2021-08-01   A
8   2021-08-01   B
```

What I want is to compute whether a user was active on a 3 month rolling basis.

For example, User `B` if we consider June (2021-06-01) we can see he was active in May and in April, thus on a 3M rolling basis he is considered Active in June. Whereas User `A` for the same time period, was not active in one of the three months, thus in June he will not be considered active.

A desired output would be to have a column which counts the Active Users (3m rolling) for each month, for example based on the above data:

```
    MONTH        Active_User_Count
0   2021-04-01   NaN
1   2021-05-01   NaN
2   2021-06-01   1
3   2021-07-01   1
4   2021-08-01   2
```

I'm still trying to get my head around rolling data, so if anyone could help me on this that would be great! Thanks in advance!

**EDIT** The `MONTH` column only has values for the 1st day of each month, but has multiple Users for that day. So there is no 2021-04-30, it all is on a monthly basis on the first day of the month.

Comment: Is the MONTH column a string, or datetime.date object, or something else?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to `groupby` `"User"` column, calculate if that user is active on a 3-mo rolling basis, then sum active users on a `groupby` `"MONTH"` column?

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp it is a Datetime object

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp yes, in simpler terms that is what I'm trying to achieve!

Comment: If you change the `'MONTH'` column object type to `pandas.Timestamp` (as simply as `df['MONTH'] = df['MONTH'].apply(pd.Timestamp)`) then you can use `df['MONTH'].diff()` to compare values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aight, let's try this.
Assuming a `pandas.DataFrame` called `df`, that has a `MONTH` column of type `pandas.Timestamp`, and a `User` column that we can `groupby`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = #[however you got your data here]
df.MONTH = df.MONTH.apply(pd.Timestamp)
```

so that e.g.

```py
>>> df
       MONTH User
0 2021-04-01    A
1 2021-04-01    B
2 2021-05-01    B
3 2021-06-01    A
4 2021-06-01    B
5 2021-07-01    A
6 2021-07-01    B
7 2021-08-01    A
8 2021-08-01    B
```

Then given the above, let's make a DataFrame to hold our result, with consecutive months from the beginning to the end of the input `DataFrame`, and initialize the active user count column to 0:

```py
res = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(df.MONTH.min(),df.MONTH.max(),freq='MS'),columns=['MONTH'])
res['Active_User_Count'] = 0
res = res.set_index('MONTH').sort_index()
```

Now to add in the values:

```py
for user, frame in df.groupby(by='User'):
    # make a helper column, that has an indicator of whether the user
    # was active that month (value='both') or not (value='right_only')
    frame = frame.merge(
                     pd.Series(pd.date_range(start=frame.MONTH.min(),\
                                        end=frame.MONTH.max(),\
                                        freq='MS'),\
                               name='MONTH'),\
                     on='MONTH',how='outer',indicator=True)\
                 .set_index('MONTH').sort_index()
    # this is where the magic happens;
    # categorize the '_merge' results (0 = left_only, 1 = right_only, 2 = both)
    # then on a 3-wide rolling window, get the minimum value
    # check that it is greater than 1.5 (i.e. all three prev months
    # are _merge value 'both')
    # if it's not > 1.5, then the user wasn't active for all 3 months
    
    # finally take the result from that rolling.min.apply,
    # and funnel into a numpy.where array, which sets
    # 'Active_User_Count' of the in-process user frame
    # to an array of 1s and 0s
    frame['Active_User_Count'] = np.where(
        (frame._merge
              .astype('category').cat.codes
              .rolling(3).min().apply(lambda x: x > 1.5)), 1, 0)
    
    # add the current-user activity into the total result
    res.Active_User_Count[frame.index] += frame.Active_User_Count

# some re-formatting
res = res.reset_index().sort_index()
```

And after all that we get our output:

```py
>>> res
       MONTH  Active_User_Count
0 2021-04-01                  0
1 2021-05-01                  0
2 2021-06-01                  1
3 2021-07-01                  1
4 2021-08-01                  2
```

## TL;DR

Here's a function to do the thing

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def active_users(df):
    res = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(df.MONTH.min(),\
                                     df.MONTH.max(),\
                                     freq='MS'),\
                       columns=['MONTH'])
    res['Active_User_Count'] = 0
    res = res.set_index('MONTH').sort_index()
    
    for user, frame in df.groupby(by='User'):
            frame = frame.merge(pd.Series(
                                    pd.date_range(start=frame.MONTH.min(),\
                                            end=frame.MONTH.max(),\
                                            freq='MS'),\
                                    name='MONTH'),\
                                on='MONTH',\
                                how='outer',\
                                indicator=True)\
                         .set_index('MONTH').sort_index()
            frame['Active_User_Count'] = np.where(
                (frame._merge
                      .astype('category')
                      .cat.codes
                      .rolling(3).min().apply(lambda x: x > 1.5)), 1, 0)
            res.Active_User_Count[frame.index] += frame.Active_User_Count
    
    return res.reset_index().sort_index()
```

Comment: It ain't pretty, and it may not be performative depending on dataframe size, but it should be a start in the direction you're looking for.

Comment: This worked - took some time cause my dataframe is rather large but the output is correct! I thought it would have been easier, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Re: took some time, this approach used a for-loop to iterate over each unique user, which is quite inefficient for large user counts. I'm sure there's a better way; I don't know what it is though ;)